# Is there the good way to use a Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a project and I have to create a thread to do a background task.
I wan't every second, refresh a count which it supposed to change with time. 
So, I create in my motherClass.cs, in the constructor, my thread like this :

```
Thread t = null;
        if (StaticContext.MyThread == null)
            StaticContext.MyThread = new Thread(new 
ThreadStart(ThreadProc));

        t = StaticContext.MyThread;
```

This is the definition of the property of MyThread, in my class StaticContext.cs :

`public static Thread MyThread { get; set; }`

This code works, my thread is created only one time, at the begininng.

Now, this is the definition of my thread start : ThreadProc, which is in my motherClass.cs :

```
public async void SetNbVoyage()
    {
        List<LogiStock.DTO.Voyage> voyages = await 
this._serviceVoyage.GetVoyageDispo();
        if (_rdm == null)
        {
            Voyage = voyages.Count.ToString();
        }
        else
            Voyage = _rdm.Next().ToString(); 
    }
    Random _rdm = null;
    public void ThreadProc()
    {
        _rdm = new Random(100);
        Task task = new Task(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {

                SetNbVoyage();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });
        task.Start();
    }
```

I did an initialisation of my Property "Voyage" before declaring the thread. 
Probleme : My thread seems to not work, in fact, the value never change, and I don't know how to see if my thread is actually working.

Comment: There's a lot of mixing and matching of threads and tasks here, with and without await, dummy-sleep being added etc. Wouldn't it be better to just rewrite the whole thing as a simple task?

Comment: My method `SetNbVoyage` needs to be asynchrone, I put a random only for testing. How can I rewrite this properly ?

Comment: Just wrap it all in a task instead of a thread, using `await Task.Delay(1000)` to wait. However, I do not know why your code doesn't work, but since you don't await your threads, if there is an exception in there it will likely go unnoticed.

Comment: All my method `SetNbVoyage` ? In a task ? Sorry but I think I don't really understand what you are telling me

Answer (score 0):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
Random _rdm = null;
IDisposable _subscription = null;

public void ThreadProc()
{
    _rdm = new Random(100);
    _subscription =
        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
            .Select(x => _rdm.Next().ToString())
            .Subscribe(x => Voyage = x);
}
```

To stop the interval timer just do `_subscription.Dispose();`. Simple.